# angularjs 1.6.4 itrate over multi dimensional JSON and loop result in html

Tags: angularjs, json, multidimensional-array

I'm stuck at logical end where I'm getting json from Request like this below:

```
"externalLinks": [
        {
            "extPageId": 10,
            "groupName": "BLAVATNIK ARCHIVE FOUNDATION",
            "title": "MISSION & HISTORY",
            "url": "http://www.mission-history/",
            "sortOrder": 1
        },
        {
            "extPageId": 9,
            "groupName": "BLAVATNIK ARCHIVE FOUNDATION",
            "title": "LEADERSHIP & STAFF",
            "url": "http://www.leadership-staff/",
            "sortOrder": 4
        },
        {
            "extPageId": 3,
            "groupName": "PROGRAMS",
            "title": "2016 PHOTOS",
            "url": "http://www.2016-photos/",
            "sortOrder": 1
        },
        {
            "extPageId": 2,
            "groupName": "PROGRAMS",
            "title": "2015 PHOTOS",
            "url": "http://www.2015-galleries/",
            "sortOrder": 2
        },
    ],
```

where my html on which i need this result to be displayed is like this:

```
            <div class="overview-box">
                <h4>BLAVATNIK ARCHIVE FOUNDATION</h4>
                <p><a target="_blank" href="http://www.mission-history/"> MISSION &amp; HISTORY<span class="stripe pdf-stripe">&nbsp;</span></a>s</p>
                <p><a target="_blank" href="http://www.collection-overview/"> COLLECTIONS OVERVIEW<span class="stripe pdf-stripe">&nbsp;</span></a></p>
                <h4>PROGRAMS</h4>
                <p><a target="_blank" href="http://www.2016-photos/"> 2016 PHOTOS<span class="stripe pdf-stripe">&nbsp;</span></a></p>
                <p><a target="_blank" href="http://www.2015-galleries/"> 2015 PHOTOS<span class="stripe pdf-stripe">&nbsp;</span></a></p>
            </div>
```

so as you can see in html, there is group name at top and below it it's content like title, url etc. So how can iterate over this json result to display content in html. I've tried to create array and some other code which i got from google but didn't found it's right logic. I can do this is PHP but here in Angular I'm fairly new:

```
$http.get(BASE_URL + "aboutdata")
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.pageTitle = response.data.pageTitle;
            var externalLinks = [];
            $scope.groupName = [];
            angular.forEach(response.data.externalLinks, function (value, key) {
                this.push(key + ': ' + value);
            }, externalLinks);
            console.log(externalLinks);
        }).finally(function () {
    // called no matter success or failure
    $scope.loading = false;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily create a dictionary out of the array, meaning each entry contain an array of the items that belong to each unique group :

```js
var groupBy = function(array, key) {
  var r = {};
  array.forEach(function(item) {
    if (r[item[key]]) {
      r[item[key]].push(item)
    } else {
      r[item[key]] = [item]
    }
  })
  return r
}

$scope.grouped_externalLinks = groupBy(externalLinks, 'groupName');
```

Now you have an array like object literal on the form

```js
{ 
 'BLAVATNIK ARCHIVE FOUNDATION': [ ... ],
 'PROGRAMS': [ ... ]
}
```

`ng-repeat` it as usual, you can even take care of the `sortOrder` within each group :

```html
<div ng-repeat="(groupName, items) in grouped_externalLinks">
  <strong> {{ groupName }} </strong>
  <div ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:'sortOrder'">
    <p><a target="_blank" href="{{ item.url }}"> {{ item.title }} </a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Best solution sir. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is `groupBy` filter. If you use that you can group based on a property inside `ng-repeat`

```
<li ng-repeat="(key, value) in data | groupBy: 'groupName'">
 <b>Group name: {{ key }}</b>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in value">
                <p><a target="_blank" href="{{item.url}}"> {{item.title}}</a></p>
      </li>
    </ul>
 </li>
```

Working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gilango/wf5x14ca/) for your reference.

NOTE: groupBy filter is not part of angular.js You have to include [angular.filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#get-started) module.